# SQL Query to count a grouped joined table by null in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 tables `products` and `stock` and `purchases`.

`Puchases` has a `primary key` of `purchaseID`.

My `products` table has a `primary key` of `productID` and then columns with details on the product.

My `stock` table has a `primary key` of `framenumber` a `foreign key` of `productID` and another `foriegn key` of `purchaseID`.

Not all products have any stock.

I would like to `join` the `prodcuts` and the stock table by the `productID` and have a row on the end which counts the amount of null values in the `purchaseID` column, which represents how many i have in stock.

I have tried a load of `queries` but seem to always just come up with total amount of entries in `stock` table or with `subqueries` not left joining properly.

Some things ive tried

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * ) AS Count
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Stock ON Products.productID = Stock.productID
WHERE Stock.OrderID IS NULL AND Stock.framenumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Products.productID
```

Just gives me the count of all the objects in stock grouped by productID and doesnt join all the products

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE BikeStock (

FrameNumber VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
BikeCode VARCHAR(40),
OrderID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (BikeCode) REFERENCES Bike(BikeCode),
FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Purchase(OrderID)
);

CREATE TABLE Bike (

BikeCode VARCHAR (40) PRIMARY KEY,
Manufacturer VARCHAR (30),
Model VARCHAR (30),
SubType VARCHAR (30),
Year SMALLINT,
FrameMaterial VARCHAR (20),
Description TEXT,
Gender VARCHAR (6),
Type VARCHAR (20),
Price DECIMAL (11,2)
);


CREATE TABLE Purchase (

DateOfPurchase DATETIME,
OrderID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),
CustomerID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID)

);
```

Comment: Please post a couple of your failed queries.

Comment: cant you post table schema with sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.productID , SUM( 
case 
   when  (Stock.OrderID IS NULL AND Stock.framenumber IS NOT NULL) 
      then 1 
      else 0 
end case
) AS Count
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Stock ON Products.productID = Stock.productID
GROUP BY Products.productID
```

Comment: Im running it with my actual schema on mysql and it wont run
   
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case ) AS Count FROM Bike LEFT JOIN BikeStock ON Bike.BikeCode = BikeStock.BikeC' at line 6   

SELECT Bike.BikeCode , SUM( 
case 
   when  (BikeStock.OrderID IS NULL) 
      then 1 
      else 0 
end case
) AS Count
FROM Bike
LEFT JOIN BikeStock ON Bike.BikeCode = BikeStock.BikeCode
GROUP BY Bike.BikeCode